# Pool based memory allocation for multi thread application

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-management, boost, boost-pool

What are the available improved Performance with Custom Pool Allocators? (e.x. in terms of the multi-thread access to the pool)

Or let's say: Is there any updated answer to this question?
[Can multithreading speed up memory allocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859263/can-multithreading-speed-up-memory-allocation) This question was asked more than 5 years ago. So I guess some updated answers would be helpful.

Comment: AFAIK a jemalloc/tcmalloc style approach is still state of the art. See doc links at http://jemalloc.net/ .

Comment: Can be boost::singleton_pool considered as thread-safe memory allocator?