# Why is there no significant difference with or without thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to evaluate the Java thread function.

1. I created a demo without thread, see below:

   ```java
   import java.util.*;

   public class NoThread {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           NoThread Obj= new NoThread();   
           Date BeforeDate = new Date();

           Obj.run();

           Date AfterDate = new Date();
           Double Time_Consume = (AfterDate.getTime()- BeforeDate.getTime())/1000.0;

           System.out.println("Time Consume= " + Time_Consume + " Seconds"  );
       }

       public void run() {
           String tmp = "";
           for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
               tmp += i;
           }   
       }

   }
   ```

   ```
   Cons

   ole display: Time Consume= 4.771 Seconds
   ```
2. I created a demo with thread.

   ```java
   import java.util.Date;

   public class ThreadTest extends Thread
   {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           ThreadTest[ ] ObjArray = new ThreadTest[5];     

           for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
               ObjArray[i]= new ThreadTest();

               Date BeforeDate = new Date();

               for(int i=0; i<5;i++ )
               {
                   ObjArray[i].start();  
               }

               try
               {
                   for(int i=0; i<5;i++ )
                       ObjArray[i].join();
               }
               catch(InterruptedException e)
               {
               }

               Date AfterDate = new Date();          
               Double Time_Consume = (AfterDate.getTime()- BeforeDate.getTime())/1000.0;
               System.out.println("Time Consume= " + Time_Consume + " Seconds"  );
       }

       public void run() {
           String tmp = "";
           for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
               tmp += i;
           }   
       }   
   }
   ```

   ```
   Time Consume= 18.658 Seconds
   ```

In the second demo, I create five threads, run the same function parallel in five threads. I expect the time consumption is similar with first project, which means close to five seconds.

However, it is much higher than my expectation, it is closer to be 5 (run times) * 4.771 = 23.85 seconds, like work in sequential.

Why?

Comment: @MarcLeBihan: Isn’t that just bad indentation?

Comment: Do you have 5 CPUs? 5 cores? What is the basis for your expectation?

Comment: Reduce the _ThreadTest_ _run_ method's _loop_ iterations to _20000_; a fifth of _100000_.

Comment: I use DELL notebook PC with 12th Generation Intel® Core™ i5 Processors i5-1245U.

From the specification, I saw:

Total Cores                10
Performance-cores    2
Efficient-cores           8

Comment: OK well this loop creates immense amounts of garbage, and the garbage collector isn't as completely multithreaded as your code is. Is there a reason why you chose String building as the test?

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems with your code, some of which directly affect the answer to your question.

To begin with, in modern Java we rarely need to directly address the `Thread` class. Instead, use the Executors framework in Java 5+. Define your task as a [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) or [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) object. Submit an instance(s) to an executor service. That [executor service](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) may be backed by a pool of threads, without you needing to manage the setup/teardown of those threads, nor do you need to manage scheduling tasks amongst those threads.

For clarity, let's move your `main` method to its own class. That way we can move your task work into a class implementing `Runnable`, meaning it implements a `run` method. No `extends Thread` at all.

Your task code does nothing productive. Nothing is passed to other code, nothing written to storage, nothing called over the network, no saving to a database, and nothing reported to the console. Such code may be optimized away by the compiler. So we add a call to `System.out.println` to avoid any such optimization.

Your task code converts an integer to text, and concatenates. In real work, we would use [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) for possibly more efficiency (though this may be done behind the scenes for you implicitly in some implementations of Java) and to make the code more self-documenting.

We want to report elapsed time for each task run.

For this, do *not* use `java.util.Date`. Indeed, do not ever use either of the `Date` classes. These were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310 for Java 8+. The `java.util.Date` class specifically was replaced by `java.time.Instant`.

For microbenchmarking, the finest time-tracking is [`System.nanoTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()). This call grabs the current value of an incrementing count of passing nanoseconds.

Use underscore to format your numeric literals for easier reading. So `100_000`.

Variable names in Java, by convention, start with a lowercase letter.

So here is our task class:

```java
package work.basil.example.looping;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;

public class Counter implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run ( )
    {
        long startNanos = System.nanoTime ( );
        StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder ( );
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 100_000 ; i++ )
        {
            tmp.append ( i );  // Converting integer number to text, and concatenating.
        }
        Duration elapsed = Duration.ofNanos ( System.nanoTime ( ) - startNanos );
        System.out.println ( "Thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread ( ).threadId ( ) + " at " + Instant.now ( ) + " result character length is: " + tmp.codePoints ( ).count ( ) + ". Elapsed: " + elapsed );
    }
}
```

Now an app class to exercise that task.

```java
package work.basil.example.looping;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App() ;
        app.demoInThisThread();
    }

    private void demoInThisThread ( )
    {
        Runnable task = new Counter () ;
        task.run() ;
    }
}
```

When run:

> Thread ID: 1 at 2023-09-17T06:01:24.691381Z result character length is: 488890. Elapsed: PT0.003877583S

On my machine (MacBook Pro, 16-inch, 2021, Apple M1 Pro, 16 GB, macOS Ventura 13.5.2), your code took PT1.456853583S. So you can see, compared to this code, how much more efficient `StringBuilder` is over `String`. But we don't really want efficiency for this threading test, so I'll restore the use of `String`.

Be aware that such a use of `String` concatenation will generate huge amounts of garbage for the garbage collector to manage, as [commented by user207421](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77120326/why-is-there-no-significant-difference-with-or-without-thread/77120709#comment135955177_77120326). So much garbage may affect results in unpredictable ways.

```java
package work.basil.example.looping;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;

public class Counter implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run ( )
    {
        long startNanos = System.nanoTime ( );
        String tmp = "";
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 100000 ; i++ ) tmp += i;
        Duration elapsed = Duration.ofNanos ( System.nanoTime ( ) - startNanos );
        System.out.println ( "Thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread ( ).threadId ( ) + " at " + Instant.now ( ) + " result character length is: " + tmp.codePoints ( ).count ( ) + ". Elapsed: " + elapsed );
    }
}
```

When run:

> Thread ID: 1 at 2023-09-17T06:09:03.218903Z result character length is: 488890. Elapsed: PT1.401553292S

Then you spawned five threads. In each you performed the same task, a loop of 100,000 iterations. So you were doing five times as much work, a total of 500,000 iterations. More work is more work, so threading is *not* going to make that extra work vanish. The CPU core(s) must still do five times as many string concatenations.

To make a more fair examination of the benefits of threading, you should divide the work so that each thread is doing a *portion* of the 100,000. We will make this possible by adding a constructor to our task class, passing the desired number of iterations.

```java
package work.basil.example.looping;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;

public class Counter implements Runnable
{
    private final int count;

    public Counter ( final int count ) { this.count = count; }

    @Override
    public void run ( )
    {
        long startNanos = System.nanoTime ( );
        String tmp = "";
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < this.count ; i++ ) tmp += i;
        Duration elapsed = Duration.ofNanos ( System.nanoTime ( ) - startNanos );
        System.out.println ( "Thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread ( ).threadId ( ) + " at " + Instant.now ( ) + " for a count of " + this.count + " produced result character length of: " + tmp.codePoints ( ).count ( ) + ". Elapsed: " + elapsed );
    }
}
```

And our app code:

```java
package work.basil.example.looping;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App ( );
        app.demoInThisThread ( );
    }

    private void demoInThisThread ( )
    {
        Runnable task = new Counter ( 100_000 );
        task.run ( );
    }
}
```

Results are the same.

Now we are ready to run five threads, each with 20,000 iterations as their portion of the 100,000.

We instantiate an executor service backed by five threads. Then we loop to submit five instances of our task to that executor service. We use try-with-resources syntax to automatically close our `ExecutorService` after the submitted tasks have completed.

```java
package work.basil.example.looping;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App ( );
//        app.demoInThisThread ( );
        app.demoInBackgroundThreads ( );
    }

    private void demoInBackgroundThreads ( )
    {
        long startNanos = System.nanoTime ( );
        try ( ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool ( 5 ) ; )
        {
            final int countTasks = 5;
            for ( int ordinal = 0 ; ordinal < countTasks ; ordinal++ )
            {
                Runnable task = new Counter ( 20_000 );
                executorService.submit ( task );
            }
        }
        Duration elapsed = Duration.ofNanos ( System.nanoTime ( ) - startNanos );
        System.out.println ( "Executor Service elapsed = " + elapsed + " at " + Instant.now ( ) );
    }

    private void demoInThisThread ( )
    {
        Runnable task = new Counter ( 100_000 );
        task.run ( );
    }
}
```

The results are startlingly different. Instead of taking well over a second, doing all 5 * 20,000 concatenations took a small fraction of a second, 1/20th of a second. Each task took about 1/20th of a second, so mathematically we know that on this 10-core machine we were getting code executing simultaneously, with each of five cores firing.

```
Thread ID: 24 at 2023-09-17T06:27:57.068636Z for a count of 20000 produced result character length of: 88890. Elapsed: PT0.1823735S
Thread ID: 23 at 2023-09-17T06:27:57.067782Z for a count of 20000 produced result character length of: 88890. Elapsed: PT0.18159025S
Thread ID: 25 at 2023-09-17T06:27:57.070629Z for a count of 20000 produced result character length of: 88890. Elapsed: PT0.18414225S
Thread ID: 22 at 2023-09-17T06:27:57.070073Z for a count of 20000 produced result character length of: 88890. Elapsed: PT0.183828875S
Thread ID: 21 at 2023-09-17T06:27:57.062894Z for a count of 20000 produced result character length of: 88890. Elapsed: PT0.176261S
Executor Service elapsed = PT0.190679125S at 2023-09-17T06:27:57.075335Z
```

So why so much faster? Well, our test is flawed. Concatenating `String` objects repeatedly results in a continually growing string. But 20,000 concatenations grows a much smaller string than 100,000 concatenations. So much smaller that much less work was involved. So this is not a good test. (Benchmarking is difficult work.)

A better test might be generating random numbers and calculating an average. On first effort, this work was so very fast that I expanded the iterations by a multiple of ten (1 million, & 200,000). And I involved `String` ↔️ `Integer` ↔️ `int` conversions as more work. Even still, we get only split second results.

The task:

```java
package work.basil.example.looping;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Averaged implements Runnable
{
    private final int count;
    private final List < String > randoms;

    public Averaged ( final int count )
    {
        this.count = count;
        this.randoms = new ArrayList <> ( this.count );
    }

    @Override
    public void run ( )
    {
        long startNanos = System.nanoTime ( );
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < this.count ; i++ )
        {
            int x = ThreadLocalRandom.current ( ).nextInt ( 1 , Integer.MAX_VALUE );
            this.randoms.add ( String.valueOf ( x ) );
        }
        double average = this.randoms.stream ( ).map ( Integer :: valueOf ).mapToInt ( Integer :: intValue ).summaryStatistics ( ).getAverage ( );  // Intentionally involved auto-boxing as extra work for our test.
        Duration elapsed = Duration.ofNanos ( System.nanoTime ( ) - startNanos );
        System.out.println ( "Thread ID: " + Thread.currentThread ( ).threadId ( ) + " at " + Instant.now ( ) + " for a count of " + this.count + " produced average of: " + average + ". Elapsed: " + elapsed );
    }
}
```

And the app class:

```java
package work.basil.example.looping;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App ( );
//        app.demoInThisThread ( );
//        app.demoInBackgroundThreads ( );
//        app.demoSumsInSameThread ( );
        app.demoSumsInBackgroundThreads ( );
    }

    private void demoSumsInBackgroundThreads ( )
    {
        long startNanos = System.nanoTime ( );
        try ( ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool ( 5 ) ; )
        {
            final int countTasks = 5;
            for ( int ordinal = 0 ; ordinal < countTasks ; ordinal++ )
            {
                Runnable task = new Averaged ( 200_000 );
                executorService.submit ( task );
            }
        }
        Duration elapsed = Duration.ofNanos ( System.nanoTime ( ) - startNanos );
        System.out.println ( "Executor Service elapsed = " + elapsed + " at " + Instant.now ( ) );
    }

    private void demoSumsInSameThread ( )
    {
        Runnable task = new Averaged ( 1_000_000 );
        task.run ( );
    }

    private void demoInBackgroundThreads ( )
    {
        long startNanos = System.nanoTime ( );
        try ( ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool ( 5 ) ; )
        {
            final int countTasks = 5;
            for ( int ordinal = 0 ; ordinal < countTasks ; ordinal++ )
            {
                Runnable task = new Counter ( 20_000 );
                executorService.submit ( task );
            }
        }
        Duration elapsed = Duration.ofNanos ( System.nanoTime ( ) - startNanos );
        System.out.println ( "Executor Service elapsed = " + elapsed + " at " + Instant.now ( ) );
    }

    private void demoInThisThread ( )
    {
        Runnable task = new Counter ( 100_000 );
        task.run ( );
    }
}
```

When run in the same thread, the million numbers take about 8/10 of a second.

```
Thread ID: 1 at 2023-09-17T07:05:24.256743Z for a count of 1000000 produced average of: 1.073135902798566E9. Elapsed: PT0.084711792S
```

When run across threads, the 200,000 * 5 numbers take about 8/10 or 9/10 of a second. Each of the threaded tasks also takes 8/10 of a second. So again, we know mathematically that on this machine we are getting separate cores running simultaneously.

```
Thread ID: 21 at 2023-09-17T07:06:14.812452Z for a count of 200000 produced average of: 1.073304324790475E9. Elapsed: PT0.080241167S
Thread ID: 23 at 2023-09-17T07:06:14.812469Z for a count of 200000 produced average of: 1.073028061541545E9. Elapsed: PT0.080389542S
Thread ID: 25 at 2023-09-17T07:06:14.813533Z for a count of 200000 produced average of: 1.07282572828644E9. Elapsed: PT0.081019291S
Thread ID: 24 at 2023-09-17T07:06:14.813595Z for a count of 200000 produced average of: 1.076256760047685E9. Elapsed: PT0.081408875S
Thread ID: 22 at 2023-09-17T07:06:14.813600Z for a count of 200000 produced average of: 1.073103576810605E9. Elapsed: PT0.081662959S
Executor Service elapsed = PT0.098596875S at 2023-09-17T07:06:14.828988Z
```

Why no savings when threaded? I don't really know why this particular task takes about the same amount of time for 200,000 as for 1 million. Again, benchmarking is difficult.

If we change the threaded test to do 10 tasks of 100,000 numbers each, on the same 10 core machine, we do see a dramatic drop in elapsed time for *some* of the tasks, taking only 2/10 of a second where we might expect 4/10. But the overall grouped time is about the same, 9/10 of a second.

```
Thread ID: 25 at 2023-09-17T19:43:06.051570Z for a count of 100000 produced average of: 1.07519247943123E9. Elapsed: PT0.057728417S
Thread ID: 24 at 2023-09-17T19:43:06.053705Z for a count of 100000 produced average of: 1.07496720067476E9. Elapsed: PT0.060560125S
Thread ID: 22 at 2023-09-17T19:43:06.053489Z for a count of 100000 produced average of: 1.07711825115815E9. Elapsed: PT0.060462083S
Thread ID: 21 at 2023-09-17T19:43:06.052852Z for a count of 100000 produced average of: 1.07550130293061E9. Elapsed: PT0.059825042S
Thread ID: 23 at 2023-09-17T19:43:06.051057Z for a count of 100000 produced average of: 1.0755424631933E9. Elapsed: PT0.057704334S
Thread ID: 21 at 2023-09-17T19:43:06.080795Z for a count of 100000 produced average of: 1.07392238112309E9. Elapsed: PT0.013798042S
Thread ID: 25 at 2023-09-17T19:43:06.081217Z for a count of 100000 produced average of: 1.07513370104224E9. Elapsed: PT0.014378042S
Thread ID: 24 at 2023-09-17T19:43:06.083975Z for a count of 100000 produced average of: 1.07646007807133E9. Elapsed: PT0.017139583S
Thread ID: 22 at 2023-09-17T19:43:06.084319Z for a count of 100000 produced average of: 1.07482906529202E9. Elapsed: PT0.017476875S
Thread ID: 23 at 2023-09-17T19:43:06.084813Z for a count of 100000 produced average of: 1.07169205436235E9. Elapsed: PT0.017668375S
Executor Service elapsed = PT0.093519875S at 2023-09-17T19:43:06.085102Z
```

Keep in mind that on this machine’s Apple Silicon M1 Pro chip, 2 of the cores are tuned for efficiency, while the other 8 are tuned for performance — this may affect results.

---

By the way… We still have a poor test regimen here. We should be doing work ahead of time to warm the JVM, etc. For real benchmarking, learn to use [JMH](https://openjdk.org/jeps/230). As mentioned, benchmarking is difficult.

---

Be aware that your test is [CPU-bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU-bound). Such a task is rather rare in real-world Java work. Quite often Java work involves [blocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_(computing)). Blocking comes from activities such as writing to storage, interacting with a database, logging, network calls such as sockets or Web services, inter-process communications, etc. For such blocking work, consider using [virtual threads](https://openjdk.org/jeps/444) ([fibers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(computer_science))) in Java 21+.

---

Beware: Output from `System.out.println` may *not* necessarily appear on the console in chronological order when called across threads. Always use a timestamp such as `Instant.now()` if you care about verifying the order.

For example, in the last example results above, notice these lines are out-of-order:

```
Thread ID: 24 at 2023-09-17T19:43:06.053705Z …
Thread ID: 22 at 2023-09-17T19:43:06.053489Z …
Thread ID: 21 at 2023-09-17T19:43:06.052852Z …
Thread ID: 23 at 2023-09-17T19:43:06.051057Z …
```

Answer (score 1):

Running multiple threads doesn't necessarily mean they all run *in parallel*. You need to have enough CPU cores to run CPU-bound code with true parallelism. If you only have one core, then your CPU-bound code will not run any faster, no matter how many threads you have. The code will probably be slower, because of the overhead of context switches and other messy things introduced by multithreading.

Having multiple threads simply makes the code run *concurrently*. If you put a `System.out.println("Done!")` at the end of `run`, you will see that they all get printed at roughly the same time. The threads are not run sequentially, one after another has finished.

Now let's say you do have enough cores to run 5 threads in parallel, then you will see your expected result if each thread does something like this:

```
int x = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < Integer.MAX_VALUE; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
        x += j + k;
    }
}
```

For me, I have 4 cores, so running 3 threads with the above code (the GC uses the last core) gives me roughly the same time as running 1 thread. If I increase it to 4 threads, the execution time starts to increase.

What makes your code slow is that you are concatenating strings, which creates new objects. And [memory can't really be allocated in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4859263/5133585). It takes ~5.3 seconds for me with 3 threads, and `3.7 seconds with 1 thread. Notice that this isn't a simple "time taken by one thread multiplied by the number of threads". There *are* places where parallelism helps, but it's just that the memory allocation can't be parallelised.

Comment: Thank you very much, I got your point, "the memory allocation is not parallel", I change the run function like yours,

Now I can see:

Run w/o thread, CPU utilization is about 30%
Time Consume= 3.998 S
Time Consume= 3.017 S
Time Consume= 2.046 S
Time Consume= 2.988 S
Time Consume= 3.008 S

Run with 4 threads, CPU utilization is about 80%. 
Time Consume= 4.545 S
Time Consume= 4.679 S
Time Consume= 4.609 S
Time Consume= 4.501 S
Time Consume= 3.998 S

The time consumption now meet my expectation, since the multithread will have execution overhead also.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... In the 2nd demo, I create 5 threads, run the same function parallel in 5 threads, I expect the time consumption is similar with 1st project, means close to 5 seconds. ..."*

I think *"concurrent"* is a better way to term a *"threaded"* process.

To elaborate, typically a program executes in a linear fashion.
This linear path is termed the *"data-flow"*, or *"[control-flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow)"*.

When a program utilizes threads, more than one *control-flow* is executed in *"parallel"*, or *"concurrently"*.
You could now visualize this path as having branched.

So, the *5* *threads* here are going to weave, or "thread" together to execute each of their own instructions, concurrently.
*CPU* time is vital.

In conclusion, the *5* threads will actually take about *5×* longer.

For *ThreadTest*, divide the *run* method's *loop* iterations, by *5*.
In this example I reduced the value from *100000* to *100*.

```java
class ThreadTest extends Thread
{
    int i, limit;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws BrokenBarrierException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ThreadTest[ ] ObjArray = new ThreadTest[5];

        int n = 100 / 5;
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            ObjArray[i]= new ThreadTest(n * i, (n * i) + n);

        Date BeforeDate = new Date();

        for(int i=0; i<5;i++ )
        {
            ObjArray[i].start();
        }

        try
        {

            for(int i=0; i<5;i++ )
                ObjArray[i].join();

        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {

        }


        Date AfterDate = new Date();
        Double Time_Consume = (AfterDate.getTime()- BeforeDate.getTime())/1000.0;
        System.out.println("Time Consume= " + Time_Consume + " Seconds"  );



    }

    ThreadTest(int i, int limit) {
        this.i = i;
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public void run() {
        String tmp = "";
        for (int i = this.i; i <= limit; i++) {
            tmp += i;
        }
    }

}
```

Here are a few comparisons.

```java
NoThread, Time Consume= 0.046 Seconds
ThreadTest, Time Consume= 0.054 Seconds

NoThread, Time Consume= 0.027 Seconds
ThreadTest Time Consume= 0.029 Seconds

NoThread, Time Consume= 0.03 Seconds
ThreadTest, Time Consume= 0.022 Seconds
```

On a final note, there is the *[CyclicBarrier](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html)* class which provides a buffer for threads working together to produce 1 value.

Comment: Makes sense but It should be a thread pool and having the threads pull the tasks from a blocking queue to make it much faster

Answer (score 0):

You guys got realize a few things about performance gains with multi-threaded code. Multi-threaded has significant time performance compared to single threads that is based on the volume of computing needed. So if you are just computing time duration a few times in one thread vs 5 you're not going to see much difference. I wrote some code for you it runs by pasting into your IDE and just change the package name.

What this shows is the current way to test multi-threaded performance in the question asked, we just don't do 5 durations we do thousands of them and we compare the time difference beteen multi-threaded and single threaded approaches, this is what this class does. You can configure the number of threads and the number of time durations to compute, that get randomly generated. The other thing that improves multi threaded performance is not by creating them one at a time but having a pool of threads that are all blocking on a queue to compute the next time duration and when the queue of durations to be computed is empty they all return and we count the time. I also used LocalDateTime and made the time duration variable betwen seconds and minutes of two datetimes.

**With that said, computing 5,000 time durations in a single thread (yes my code added some overhead in building responses, still relative) was 0.152359333 seconds, when doing the same number in a multithreaded blocking queue approach with 3 threads each concurrently a sub set of durations the time is  0.005566667 seconds , which is about **27 times faster**,**

That is where you want to be using threads to see real performance, another good example is ingesting bulk data into a sql database, create a blockingQueue of records to inset have a thread that bulk inserts records off the queue, create 5 of those threads and your insert time improves 40X times. Hope that sheds some light.

Here is 10000 durations to compute with 5 threads vs 1..
It shows the principle of increased performance of multithreading based on computing volume.

**10000 durations Time Duration Tasks Single Thread took 0.343375458
Thread Pool size 5 tooked 0.004482167 seconds to compute  10000 durations
Multi threaded is 76.60925128403294 time faster**
This is the code change the package name. no other third party imports

```
package com.dunkware.trade.service.beach.server.entity;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class Test {

// play these variables, interesting to see 
// that 3 threads are faster than 5 threads
// might be the overhead for creting them
// in real life it should come from a thread pool 

// it tells you with thee values multithreaded is 27 times faster.
public static int COMPUTE_COUNT = 5000;
public static int THREAD_COUNT = 3;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test();

    test.SingleThreaded5000Requests();
    test.multiThreadedRequests();
    
    
    
}

public static double singleTime; 
public static double multiTime;

private static BlockingQueue<TimeDurationRequest> requestQuueu = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
private static BlockingQueue<DuraionProcessThread> doneThreadQueue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<DuraionProcessThread>();

public static final List<DurationResponse> multiThreadResponses = new ArrayList<DurationResponse>();


private void multiThreadedRequests() { 
    List<DuraionProcessThread> threads = new ArrayList<Test.DuraionProcessThread>();
    int i = 0;
    while(i < COMPUTE_COUNT) { 
        requestQuueu.add(randomRequest());
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    DStopWatch timer = DStopWatch.create();
    timer.start();
    while(i < THREAD_COUNT) { 
        DuraionProcessThread thread = new DuraionProcessThread();
        thread.start();
        threads.add(thread);
        i++;
    }

    
    timer.stop();
    multiTime = timer.getCompletedSeconds();
    System.out.println("Thread Pool size " + THREAD_COUNT + " tooked " + timer.getCompletedSeconds() + " seconds to compute  " + COMPUTE_COUNT + " durations");
    double  faster = singleTime / multiTime;
    System.out.println("Multi threaded is " + faster + " time faster");
}
private static class DuraionProcessThread extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        while (!interrupted()) {
            try {

                TimeDurationRequest req = Test.requestQuueu.poll(5, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

                if ((req == null)) {
                    // all requests consumed return trhead
                    doneThreadQueue.add(this);
                    return;
                }

                Number duration = getDurationBetween(req.getUnit(), req.stat, req.stop);
                DurationResponse res = new DurationResponse();
                res.value = duration;
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                if (req.unit == ChronoUnit.SECONDS) {
                    builder.append("Time Duration in seconds is ").append(duration).append(" fom ")
                            .append(req.getStat().toString()).append(" to ").append(req.getStop().toString());
                    res.messsae = builder.toString();
                    multiThreadResponses.add(res);
                }
                builder = new StringBuilder();
                if (req.getUnit() == ChronoUnit.MINUTES) {
                    
                    builder.append("Time Duration in minutes is ").append(duration).append(" fom ")
                            .append(req.getStat().toString()).append(" from ").append(req.getStop().toString());
                    res.messsae = builder.toString();
                    multiThreadResponses.add(res);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

        }

    }
}

/***
 * First break your logic into some helper methods, if you have a reason to sue
 * java.util.date be it, LocalDateTime are better you can easily get duration of
 * dates and date/time ranges.
 */

/**
 * Also more efficient, one function and pass in a date/time range and specify
 * what duration unit you want, seconds, minutes or whatever.
 * 
 * @param from
 * @param to
 * @return
 */
public static long getDurationBetween(ChronoUnit unit, LocalDateTime from, LocalDateTime to) {
    return unit.between(from, to);
}

// another util for stop watch
public static class DStopWatch {

    public enum Status {
        Started, Stopped, Initialized;
    }

    public static DStopWatch create() {
        return new DStopWatch();
    }

    private volatile DStopWatch.Status _status = DStopWatch.Status.Initialized;
    private TimeUnit _timeUnit = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS;
    private Long _startTime = null;
    private Long _stopTime = null;

    DStopWatch() {

    }

    public Status getStatus() {
        return _status;
    }

    public void start() {
        if (_timeUnit == TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS) {
            _startTime = System.nanoTime();
            _stopTime = null;
            setStatus(Status.Started);
        }
        if (_timeUnit == TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) {
            _startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            _stopTime = null;
        }

    }

    void setStatus(Status status) {
        _status = Status.Stopped;
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (getStatus() != Status.Stopped) {
            // exception
        }
        if (_timeUnit == TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS) {
            _stopTime = System.nanoTime();
            setStatus(Status.Stopped);
        }
        if (_timeUnit == TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) {
            _stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

    }

    public void reset() {
        setStatus(Status.Initialized);
        _startTime = null;
        _stopTime = null;

    }

    public TimeUnit getTimeUnit() {
        return _timeUnit;
    }

    public void reset(TimeUnit timeUnit) {
        _timeUnit = timeUnit;
        reset();
    }

    public double getRunningSeconds() {
        long dureation = System.nanoTime() - _startTime;
        double seconds = ((double) dureation) / 1E9;
        return seconds;
    }

    public double getCompletedSeconds() {
        long dureation = _stopTime - _startTime;
        double seconds = ((double) dureation) / 1E9;
        return seconds;
    }

}

/**
 * Next i would build a model object for what you are trying to compute if its a
 * model easier to make a REST API out of it.
 */

public static class TimeDurationRequest {
    private ChronoUnit unit;
    private LocalDateTime stat;
    private LocalDateTime stop;

    public ChronoUnit getUnit() {
        return unit;
    }

    public void setUnit(ChronoUnit unit) {
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getStat() {
        return stat;
    }

    public void setStat(LocalDateTime stat) {
        this.stat = stat;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getStop() {
        return stop;
    }

    public void setStop(LocalDateTime stop) {
        this.stop = stop;
    }

}

// helper
public static int getRandomNumber(int min, int max) {
    return (int) ((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
}

public static int timeUnitIterator = 0;

// make a random generator for testing performance
private static TimeDurationRequest randomRequest() {

    TimeDurationRequest req = new TimeDurationRequest();
    if (timeUnitIterator == 0) {
        req.setUnit(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
        timeUnitIterator = 1;
    } else {
        req.setUnit(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
        timeUnitIterator = 0;

    }

    req.setStat(LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(getRandomNumber(0, 42)));
    req.setStop(LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(getRandomNumber(0, 2)));
    return req;
}

public static class DurationResponse {

    public String messsae;
    private Number value;

}

// okay sow now lets test it to really make a multi-threaded service you best
// using a thread poool and a blockign quueue to bulk process and test
// perfomrnace.

private void SingleThreaded5000Requests() {
    List<DurationResponse> responses = new ArrayList<DurationResponse>();
    int i = 0;
    DStopWatch timer = DStopWatch.create();
    timer.start();
    while (i < COMPUTE_COUNT) {
        TimeDurationRequest req = randomRequest();
        Number duration = getDurationBetween(req.getUnit(), req.stat, req.stop);
        DurationResponse res = new DurationResponse();
        res.value = duration;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        if (req.unit == ChronoUnit.SECONDS) {
            builder.append("Time Duration in seconds is ").append(duration).append(" fom ")
                    .append(req.getStat().toString()).append(" to ").append(req.getStop().toString());
            res.messsae = builder.toString();
            responses.add(res);
        }
        builder = new StringBuilder();
        if (req.getUnit() == ChronoUnit.MINUTES) {
            builder.append("Time Duration in minutes is ").append(duration).append(" fom ")
                    .append(req.getStat().toString()).append(" from ").append(req.getStop().toString());
            res.messsae = builder.toString();
            responses.add(res);
        }
        i++;
    }
    timer.stop();
    singleTime = timer.getCompletedSeconds();
    System.out.println(COMPUTE_COUNT + " durations Time Duration Tasks Single Thread took " + timer.getCompletedSeconds());
    //System.out.println("results....");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (

    Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
//  for (DurationResponse durationResponse : responses) {
    //  System.out.println(durationResponse.messsae);
//  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behavior is that Java threads do not necessarily run in parallel, especially on a single-core machine. Java virtual machine schedules threads on the underlying hardware, and if you only have one core, the threads will be scheduled to run one after the other. Even on a multi-core machine, there is no guarantee that the JVM will schedule the threads to run in parallel. The actual behavior can depend on many factors, including the specific JVM implementation and the current load on the system.

Additionally, the overhead of creating and managing threads can also add to the total execution time. Threads in Java are not lightweight entities, and creating a large number of them can be quite expensive in terms of both time and memory.

The specific task that your threads are performing (concatenating strings in a loop) is not a good candidate for parallelization. The += operation for strings in Java creates a new object every time, as strings in Java are immutable. This is computationally expensive and may also put pressure on the garbage collector when done in a loop, especially within multiple threads. You may replacae += with StringBuilder, to see if there will be any difference on your system.

There are also other factors to take into account, like being cache friendly. CPUs have limited memory for various cache levels. If your threads work on separate data sets, then the context switch between execution of threads might require cache invalidation which can slow down the program.

You may try parallel streams which optimizes parallel computations, below is sample code which will compare threads solutions with parallels stream, and other aproaches:

```
package org.example;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class ParallelAndThreadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //single thread
        System.out.println("single thread:");
        testTime(() -> runSingleThread(ParallelAndThreadTest::performTask));

        //multiple threads
        System.out.println("multiple threads:");
        testTime(() -> runWithThreads(ParallelAndThreadTest::performTask));

        //parallel streams - uses ForkJoinPool, but is a lot faster than
        //the later example using ForkJoinPool directly. (at least on my system).
        System.out.println("parallel streams:");
        testTime(() -> runInParallel(ParallelAndThreadTest::performTask));

        //executorService
        System.out.println("executorservice:");
        testTime(() -> runWithExecutorService(ParallelAndThreadTest::performTask));

        //ForkJoinPool
        //just to compare with the parallel streams solution.
        System.out.println("ForkJoinPool:");
        testTime(() -> runWithForkJoinPool(ParallelAndThreadTest::performTask));
    }

    public static void testTime(Runnable task) {
        long totalTime = 0;
        int runs = 200;//200 runs to get a good average

        for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
            long before = System.nanoTime();
            task.run();
            long after = System.nanoTime();
            totalTime += (after - before);
        }

        double averageTime = (totalTime / (double) runs) / 1_000_000_000.0;  // Converting to seconds
        String formattedTime = String.format("%.4f", averageTime);
        System.out.println("Average Time Consume = " + formattedTime + " Seconds");
    }

    //your initial code to test, its really slow...
    public static void performTask2() {
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            s += "" + i;
        }
    }

    public static void performTask() {
        StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            tmp.append(i);
        }
    }

    public static void runSingleThread(Runnable task) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            task.run();
        }
    }

    public static void runWithThreads(Runnable task) {
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            threads[i] = new Thread(task);
            threads[i].start();
        }
        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            try {
                thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void runInParallel(Runnable task) {
        IntStream.range(0, 5).parallel().forEach(i -> task.run());
    }

    public static void runWithExecutorService(Runnable task) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            executorService.execute(task);
        executorService.shutdown();
        while (!executorService.isTerminated()) {}
    }

    public static void runWithForkJoinPool(Runnable task) {
        ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(5);
        forkJoinPool.submit(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                forkJoinPool.invoke(new RecursiveActionEx(task));
            }
        }).join();
    }

    static class RecursiveActionEx extends RecursiveAction {
        private final Runnable task;

        RecursiveActionEx(Runnable task) {
            this.task = task;
        }

        @Override
        protected void compute() {
            task.run();
        }
    }
}
```

I have used StringBuilder for concatenation, on my system it outputs:

```
single thread:
Average Time Consume = 0.0064 Seconds
multiple threads:
Average Time Consume = 0.0023 Seconds
parallel streams:
Average Time Consume = 0.0020 Seconds
executorservice:
Average Time Consume = 0.0024 Seconds
ForkJoinPool:
Average Time Consume = 0.0060 Seconds
```

I have 8 cores. The parallel streams solution always win sligthly.

On my mac I can disable certain cores with cpuctl command, I have disabled all 7 cores leaving only one, and got this results:

```
single thread:
Average Time Consume = 0.0237 Seconds
multiple threads:
Average Time Consume = 0.0145 Seconds
parallel streams:
Average Time Consume = 0.0212 Seconds
executorservice:
Average Time Consume = 0.0173 Seconds
ForkJoinPool:
Average Time Consume = 0.0111 Seconds
```

now, the ForkJoinPool is the fastest.